# Soap request in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, soap

I'm trying to use TypeScript to run a SOAP request, but I'm getting an error when I compile the code with **"tsc myfile.ts"**. The code:

```
import Soap from 'soap';

function soapClientServer(){
    
const url = 'myurl'

Soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
if(err){
    console.log(err)
}else{
    console.log('connection with SOAP OK')
    client.consultaNFSe({
      token: 'mytoken',
      cnpj: 'mydata',
      nrNota: '',
      nrPedido: 'mydata'
    }, (err, res) =>{
        return console.log(res)
    })
  }
})

}

export default soapClientServer()
```

The error:

```
index.ts:1:8 - error TS1192: Module '"/Users/vinicius.siqueira/Projects/MyPC/soap-typescript/node_modules/soap/lib/soap"' has no default export.

1 import Soap from 'soap';
         ~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use this: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap
But I'm new to TS, tryin to figure out how to create the same with TypeScript. I've tried with simple node code and worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import {createClient} from 'soap';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was importing incorrectly, sorry for that. Besides that error, now I'm getting this on my terminal:

Error: write EPROTO 4550297024:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16) {
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}

Comment: Have a google around for that error code, and if you don't get anything, ask a separate question as it is unrelated to this one.

Comment: I've figured it out, it was a protocol/certificate problem, Node problems. Tks Luke!